# Express the statement that $x$ has at least one element in the language of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a past paper for a module that I am revising for, we are asked to express the Axiom Schema of Separation for the property that "$x$ has at least one element".

I understand that the Axiom Schema of Separation for a general property can be written as
$$
\forall z\forall w_1\forall w_2\dotsb\forall w_n\exists y\forall x\left[\left(x\in y\right)\leftrightarrow\left(\left(x\in z\right)\wedge\left({\phi}\left({x,w_1,w_2,\dotsc,w_n}\right)\right)\right)\right],
$$
but I am not sure how to change this to the specific example given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write the property $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)$ holds if and only if $x$ is not empty (which is equivalent to saying that $x$ has at least one element).

There's no need for parameters for this property. Just the obvious thing. $x$ is not empty if it has an element.

Comment: So in this case it would be ¬(x=∅). What would have to be done if instead it said "x has at most one element"?

Comment: No, $\varnothing$ is not part of the language of set theory. The language of set theory has only $\in$ (and $=$ in modern treatments). How do you say that something has exactly one element? Now say that something has at most one element if it is empty, or has exactly one element.

Comment: Exactly one element in x: ∃!w(w∈x)
No element in x: ¬∃w(w∈x)

At most one element: (¬∃w1(w1∈x))∨(∃!w2(w2∈x))

Comment: I don't know what you were taught, $\exists !$ is a shorthand, and you may or may not be allowed to use it. But yes, other than that it's fine.

Comment: A slightly neater way of saying there is at most one element of a set $x$ is $$\forall w_1 \forall w_2 (w_1 \in x \wedge w_2 \in x \to w_1=w_2)$$

Comment: Just to confirm, in the case where we have "$x$ contains at most one element", would the final Axiom Schema for Separation be written as
$$
\forall z\forall w_1\forall w_2\forall w_3\exists y\forall x\left[\left(x\in y\right)\leftrightarrow\left(\left(x\in z\right)\wedge\left(\neg\left(w_1\in x\right)\vee\left(\left(\left(w_2\in x\right)\wedge\left(w_3\in x\right)\right)\rightarrow\left(w_2=w_3\right)\right)\right)\right)\right]
$$